What happens when a CodeEffect rule's .Net source object member(s) change?
Just wondering how this scenario is handled by the rules engine and UI. So if a rule I've created references a property or method 'A', and that property or method changes to 'B' (or perhaps method signature changes, or underlying type changes), does the UI mark portions of the ruleset that have become invalid, display an error, or do they disappear, or display as normal until execution and result in an exception/error?
Haven't played with any demo code on this product yet, I've just taken an initial look and the thought crossed my mind that the underlying models I'd be building rules on could change in different ways over time. I'm particularly interested in the UI side, wondering how it would look to an end-user that may have permission to manage certain business rules on top of data models that end up changing.

The editor highlights the now invalid properties and methods and displays the warning message in the Help String if it's visible. The user can hoover his mouse over highlighted rule elements to see the detailed message.

Ah ok.  Does it allow making corrections to those rule elements at that point, or must they be deleted and re-created?
